# Авторизация и аутентификация WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, веб-служба

Доброго времени суток!
Надо реализовать   **Авторизацию и аутентификацию** на стороне службы WCF по протоколу SOAP.Кто может показать хотя бы маленький пример правильной реализации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, пример с хабра [Клац](https://habrahabr.ru/company/dataart/blog/262817/)

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв.Статья полезная но там описаны разные возможности  для аутентификации и авторизации по потребности написанной приложении.Хотелось бы иметь кодовый пример для аутентификации и авторизации или же только  авторизации .